# Shopify & Rails: Webhook being fired multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, webhooks

I have a new customer webhook that is firing multiple times whenever a new customer is created.  I've confirmed by connecting via the API that only the one webhook exists in my test shop.

```
def new_customer_callback    <<< ---- gets called multiple times
    # here I create a customer in my app, 
    # but the customer has some custom validations that take a while

    head :ok
end
```

My thought is that maybe the webhook keeps firing until head :ok gets returned. So because my customers.create custom validations are taking so long, the webhook gets fired multiple times.

Is this correct? What's a good way to avoid this? I don't want to bog down my app running multiple unnecessary callbacks

Answer (score 2):

Shopify has a 5-second timeout before it retries the request.

[Respond to a webhook](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks#respond-to-webhook)

If your app takes time to process the request, you need to add the request to a queue, respond immediately to the request and then process the request later. You can also run it in a different thread or in parallel but you need to make sure Shopify receives a response as quickly as possible to avoid the timeout.